# Pandas how to import a txt file as a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a names.txt file that is a list of names, each name is on a new line:

```
   'Fred',
   'Ed',
   'George'
```

I want to open my txt file, extract the names and add it to a list with nice looking formatting. When I try

```
    list=[]
    names = open(names.txt)
    for s in names:
        display(s)
        list.append(s)
```

The output looks like the below

```
    "     'Fred',/n"
    "     'Ed',/n"
    "     'George',/n"
```

Naturally I get a list, but I want my list to be `list = ['Fred','Ed','George']`  not with the `/n`, `""` and extra spaces. Does anyone know the best way to get rid of the extra white space and the /n line. I could take 2-3 steps to replace everything, but does anyone know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure the format is as you describe in the question, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

data = literal_eval('[' + open('your_file.txt', 'r').read() + ']')

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
['Fred', 'Ed', 'George']
```

Comment: Nice out-of-the-box thinking!

Answer (score 1):

Atypical use for `pandas`, but this is basically comma-separated values:

```
In[0]:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('names.txt', header=None)

ls = df[0].str.strip().str.replace("'",'').to_list()
ls

Out[0]:

['Fred', 'Ed', 'George']
```

`str.strip()` to remove whitespace and then `str.replace()` to remove the extra single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Will this help:

```
with open('names.txt','r') as f:
    
    lst = f.readlines()

lst = [l.strip()[:-1].strip("'") for l in lst]

print(lst)
print('\n'.join(lst))
```

Output:

```
['Fred', 'Ed', 'George']
Fred
Ed
George
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Pandas for this, you can just do:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

names = [name.strip("', ") for name in data.splitlines()]
```

Comment: There are extra quotes in the strings.