# How to import list stored as txt into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following problem. I need to load txt file as pandas dataframe. See, how my txt looks like:

```
[        {
            "type": "VALUE",
            "value": 93.5,
            "from": "2020-12-01T00:00:00.000+01",
            "to": "2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01"
        },
        {
            "type": "VALUE",
            "value": 75,
            "from": "2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01",
            "to": "2020-12-01T00:05:01.000+01"
        },
        {
            "type": "WARNING",
            "from": "2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01",
            "to": "2020-12-01T00:05:01.000+01"
        } ]
```

In other words, I need to read the txt as a list of dictionaries. And then read it as a pandas dataframe. Desired output is:

```
      type       value    from                             to
0     VALUE      93.5     2020-12-01T00:00:00.000+01       2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01
1     VALUE      75       2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01       2020-12-01T00:05:01.000+01
2     WARNING    NaN      2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01       2020-12-01T00:05:01.000+01
```

How can I do this, please? I look at this question, but it wasn`t helpful: [Pandas how to import a txt file as a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522649/pandas-how-to-import-a-txt-file-as-a-list) , [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: How working `df = pd.read_json('file.txt')` ?

Comment: @jezrael - I shame, how simple it was. I was overthinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html), because if extension is `txt` still it is json file:

```
df = pd.read_json('file.txt')
    
print (df)
      type  value                        from                          to
0    VALUE   93.5  2020-12-01T00:00:00.000+01  2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01
1    VALUE   75.0  2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01  2020-12-01T00:05:01.000+01
2  WARNING    NaN  2020-12-01T00:00:01.000+01  2020-12-01T00:05:01.000+01
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('inp_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame(content)
```